# Generate transition matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have two very large matrices and I need to compute the transition matrix, for example:
Matrix A

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
2 1 3
```

Matrix B:

```
3 2 1
1 2 3
3 2 1
```

Then the transition matrix should be:

```
   1    2    3
1  0   1/3  2/3
2  0   2/3  1/3
3  1    0    0
```

I am currently using nested for loop to iterate both matrices and then increment the number in my transition matrix, but it is extremely slow. Is there a more efficient way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: A transition matrix is a stochastic matrix of probabilities. What is _your_ definition of a transition matrix?

Comment: Sorry, what I want is the stochastic matrix of probabilities, but I think when you get all the numbers of transition, calculating the probabilities is easy. Thanks!

Comment: I changed my sample transition matrix.

Comment: What are the permissible "states" (entries) of your matrices? just small integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `a` and `b` are NumPy arrays. You can construct the TM as a SciPy sparse matrix:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.sparse as sp
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]])
b = np.array([[3,2,1],[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
```

Find and count all actual transitions:

```
cntr = Counter(chain.from_iterable(list(zip(*x)) for x in (zip(a,b))))
#Counter({(3, 1): 3, (1, 3): 2, (2, 2): 2, (1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1})
```

Construct a sparse matrix of counts, where the rows and columns represent the states:

```
transition = sp.csr_matrix((list(cntr.values()), zip(*cntr.keys())))
```

Normalize the matrix:

```
transition[1:,1:] / transition[1:,1:].sum(axis=1)
#array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.66666667],
#       [ 0.        ,  0.66666667,  0.33333333],
#       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Unly quibble I have is using `a.max()` and `b.max()`, wich will fail if, for example, the initial matrices are zero-indexed (or have non-sequential values)

Comment: Thank you! I found your answer is really helpful. I was testing it on my data yesterday. Although it is slower than Daniel F's answer, it takes much less memory, about 10,000 MB for my 50000*50000 matrices.

Answer (score 2):

A more general trasntition matrix constructor using `np.add.at`:

```
def trans(A, B):

    Au, Ar = np.unique(A, return_inverse = 1)
    Bu, Br = np.unique(B, return_inverse = 1)
    indices = (Ar.ravel(), Br.ravel())
    out = np.zeros((Au.size, Bu.size))
    np.add.at(out, indices, 1)
    out /= out.sum(axis = 1)
    return out, Au, Bu

trans(A, B)
Out:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.66666667],
       [ 0.        ,  0.66666667,  0.33333333],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `axis = 0`, not 1? Shouldn't the matrix be row-stochastic?

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense.  I wasn't sure which way to normalize.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Thanks for solving my question, however, I got a memory error when running this on my data. My matrices are about 50000*50000, and I have a 32GB RAM computer. Thank you so much!

Comment: My dataset is too large, so I just keep python running during the weekend. I think I will see the result on Monday!

Answer (score 2):

Same overall approach as @DanielF, faster (10x in my test case) implementation. The trick is avoiding `np.add.at` which is very useful but not the fastest. I leave out the steps that would be the same between the two variants (finding uniques and normalizing probabilities).

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100))
>>> B = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100))
>>> 
>>> def f_df(A, B):
...     out = np.zeros((100, 100), int)
...     np.add.at(out, (A.ravel(), B.ravel()), 1)
...     return out
... 
>>> def f_pp(A, B):
...     return np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index((A, B), (100, 100)).ravel(), minlength=10000).reshape(100, 100)
... 
>>> np.all(f_df(A, B) == f_pp(A, B))
True
>>> 
>>> repeat('f_df(A, B)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
[0.7909002639353275, 0.7779529448598623, 0.7819221799727529]
>>> repeat('f_pp(A, B)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
[0.07678529410623014, 0.07394189992919564, 0.0735252988524735]
```

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for solving my problems. I learned a lot from your answer. However, I ran into the same memory error issue as Daniel F's answer. I guess my dataset is too huge? I have matrices of about 50000*50000 size, and my computer has 32GB memory. Thanks!